# Mocking lambda-log options.meta using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

In my `util.ts` I am importing and using `lambda-log`:

util.ts

```
import * as logger from 'lambda-log';

export async function prepareMessage(req){
   try {
      logger.options.meta.clientId = req.clientId;
   
      if (!req.templateId) {
         throw new Error(`template is missing`);
      }
   } catch(error){
     logger.error('error occured', error);
   }
}
```

I want to test in my `util.test.ts` that logger.error contains `clientId` I set in options.meta.clientId.
This is what I got so far, but it is not working:

util.test.ts

```
import * as logger from 'lambda-log';
jest.mock('lambda-log', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('lambda-log'),
    error: jest.fn()
}));

it('sets clientId in logger.options.meta from request payload', async () => {
   const record = { clientId: 'client-test' };
   const optionsSpy = jest.spyOn(logger, 'error');

   try {
      await prepareMessage(record);
   } catch (err) {
      
      expect(optionsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

      expect(optionsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
           clientId: 'client-test'
         })
      );
   }
}
```

Does anyone know how to spy `lambda-log` and how to accomplish this?

Comment: Your test case will throw an error with the `'template is missing'` message. The error will not contain `clientId`. how to spy `lambda-log`?  What exactly do you want to spy and test? Please clarify.

Comment: @slideshowp2 If you see above, I am interested in the logger object and its' options.meta property being set. And I thought I can somehow spy on it and test that it indeed was called with my clientId.

My catch calls logger, and it is this logger that I want to analyze and determine that its' options.meta contains clientId that I set within try clause.